# Div layout using horizontal scroll (no table)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, loops, layout

Is it possible to get this layout :

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 etc..
```

without separating the divs (I need it for one single wordpress loop, and I dont know how to run it if div's are separated) 
since I'm using horizontal scroll on parent div. 
I tried using `nth-of-type() or nth-child()` combined with float, clear, display, and no luck so far

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/33xudLcv/7/)
html:

```
<div class="row-horizon">
  <div class="element">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
```

CSS:

```
.row-horizon {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 57vw;
}

.element {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}



.element:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: left; top:5px; position:relative;}
```

Comment: Do your target platforms support flexbox?

Comment: Currently using bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit dirty, but it may suffice for you. Here is an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33xudLcv/8/) from yours.

First get rid of the [inline-block spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) in your HTML, for example like this:

```
<div class="row-horizon">
    <div class="element">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 1</h1>
    </div><div class="element">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 2</h1>
    </div><div class="element">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 3</h1>
    </div><div class="element">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 4</h1>
    </div><div class="element">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 5</h1>
    </div><div class="element">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 6</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change CSS to:

```
.row-horizon {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:57vw;
}

.element {
    display: inline-block;
    /* white-space: normal; */
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.8);
    height:40%;
    width:330px; /* added width */
    margin-right:20px; /* added a white space width */
}

.element h1 {
    font-size:15; 
    font-family:Arial; 
    padding:50px;
}

.element:nth-child(2n) { /* every second div */
    margin-left:-350px; /* substract .element width + white space width */
    margin-top:200px; /* height of .element + white space in height */
}
```